# CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER with a custom header with an accent is not processed correctly

Tags: php, curl

I'm sending a custom value in the header that has an accent but curl is not processing the accent. Here is the code:

```
$headers = array(
    'environment: testé',
);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://test.url.com/getStuff',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
));
```

The API is receiving this value in the header as "teste' ". note the single quote after the letter e.

Comment: Not for sure, but perhaps CURLOPT_ENCODING is needed?

Comment: Thanks. I added CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip,deflate' but it didn't work.

Comment: Headers must be ASCII so you will need to encode it, how is up to you (json with javascript escapes/to binary then base64/percent encoding etc)

Comment: Thanks Alex K. We fixed it byt adding this code:    $ambiente = "environment: testé";
    $myEnvironment = iconv(
        mb_detect_encoding($myEnvironment),
        'UTF-8',
        $myEnvironment
    );